Nextjs - input field turns white when selecting an email
I have this login form in Nextjs using tailwind. When selecting an email(saved in google chrome) the input field turns white. How can I solve this?
enter image description here
I tried adding a focus but this didn't solve it.
enter image description here

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You can use :autofill CSS pseudo-class when an  element has its value autofilled by the browser. However you cannot change the  background-color, background-image, or color because many browsers use !important in their :-webkit-autofill style declarations.
That is why I searched a little bit a found another solution using background clip.


input:autofill,
input:autofill:hover,
input:autofill:focus,
input:autofill:active {
  background-clip: text;
}



In this way instead of trying to change the background color, we painted background within (clipped to) the foreground text. As I checked MDN documents they are compatible with all browsers.
Check this references for more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill

